# Can't remove a black line that is over a picture

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm using `[BJImageCropper]`[1](https://github.com/barrettj/BJImageCropper) and trying to figure out how to remove the squares effect around the crop area. I want to have a full area of black alpha around the crop area. Sounds easy, so the only thing I changed in the above project was changing the `alpha to 0.75` in `BJImageCropper.m:`

```
- (UIView*)newEdgeView {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    view.alpha = 0.75;    //(was 0.5)
    [self.imageView addSubview:view];    
    return view;
}
```

My problem is that there's a black line that's following me around in the top right corner of the crop area. matter what I changed in the code - I can't get rid of.

[image]